# Social Framework iOS 8 swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I've been writing an app that needs to use Social framework to share text via Twitter and Facebook.

I got it to work but it did not dismiss (?), Then I remembered the completion handler, but whatever I do this handler keeps on giving me errors.

```
var okFacebook :Bool = SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeFacebook)
var okTwitter :Bool = SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeTwitter)
var okLinkedIn : Bool = SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeLinkedIn)
var socialVC :SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter)
        
socialVC.completionHandler = SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler(SLComposeViewControllerResult) -> Void
self.presentViewController(socialVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Please note: "SLServiceTypeLinkedIn" is not available in iOS, as of iOS10.3, only on macOS10.9+

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try the following code, not yet tested

```
 socialVC.completionHandler = {
    (result:SLComposeViewControllerResult) in
        // Your code
    }
```

Comment: Thanks man but i figured out like 20 minutes after i posted lol ill still mark your answer as correct but i did it differently

Comment: socialVC.completionHandler = {result -> Void in

            var r = result as SLComposeViewControllerResult
            switch(r.toRaw())
                {
            case SLComposeViewControllerResult.Cancelled.toRaw():
                println("Cancelled")
            case SLComposeViewControllerResult.Done.toRaw():
                println("Done")
            default:
                println("Something went wrong")
            }
            
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }

Comment: There is a mistake in my code also. i just corrected it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeFacebook){
        var facebookSheet:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)


        facebookSheet.setInitialText("Hiya, I have just discovered this great app called Dwingle, which I think you're going to love.")
        let url = NSURL(string: "")
        facebookSheet.addURL(url)
        self.presentViewController(facebookSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)


        facebookSheet.completionHandler = {

            result -> Void in
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in
                self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
            })
        }


    } else {
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Accounts", message: "Please login to a Facebook account to share.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```