# How can i attach a video file to Publish on Facebook with iOS8 Social Framework Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, ios8, social-framework

I am currently following this Topic: [Social Framework iOS 8 swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24528854/social-framework-ios-8-swift) and I have successfully finished it.

Here is my complete code in Swift:

```
import Social
```

and

```
@IBAction func shareFB(sender : AnyObject) {
    if(SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeFacebook))
    {
        var SocialMedia :SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)

        SocialMedia.completionHandler = {
            result -> Void in


            var getResult = result as SLComposeViewControllerResult;
            switch(getResult.toRaw()) {
            case SLComposeViewControllerResult.Cancelled.toRaw(): println("Cancelled")
            case SLComposeViewControllerResult.Done.toRaw(): println("It's Work!")
            default: println("Error!")
            }
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }
        self.presentViewController(SocialMedia, animated: true, completion: nil)
        SocialMedia.setInitialText("Test a Post on Facebook")
    }


}
```

If I want to attach or upload a video file to Publish on Facebook by Social Framework, 
how or not possible? if not What should I do?
Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can only add text, urls and image.

Look on the Compose Post Section here for more information.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler

What you will have to share is the video url.